# Regular Expressions for restricting _ at the end

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression `^[\\p{L}\\d._]*\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\d._]*$`  and this works fine for

1. `ABC123de` (alphanumeric - irrespective of the case)
2. `ABCDEfgh` (only alphabets - irrespective of the case)
3. `Abc_.123` (only special characters allowed are `_` and `.`)

However, it is accepting inputs like

1. `balaji_,jacob_` (having `_` at the end)
2. `2balaji,2jacob` (starting with a numeric)

Can we modify the above regular expression to restrict the above two test cases?

Comment: Please learn regex yourself. You have been asking question on this regex too many times already.

Comment: [This tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) will help you.

Comment: Please see final sentence of my answer: you need to better define what is allowed. As defined "`_.`", "`.1`" and "`_1`" are allowed: is this correct? Suggestion: define positively (ie. what is allowed): for length, for starting character, for end character and for other (middle) characters.

Comment: Sorry, just want to confirm that is why, thanks it is working tested thorougly, Im struggling with it for the past 2 days , thinking that I got the solution and then realizing that I did not check properly. It is fine now, without your solution, this would take ages for me to complete and who knows without the result even, Thanks Keppil

Comment: @Richard, thanks for your steps so that I can understand clearly, and I will try to be clear in my question . Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, add the appropriate restrictions to the beginning and end like this:

```
^\p{L}[\p{L}\d._]*\p{L}+[\p{L}\d._]*[\p{L}\d.]$
```

Comment: That would allow anything that isn't an underscore at the end, so "`A%`" will match. You've also removed the ability to start with a digit, period or underscore.

Comment: Well, starting with a digit shouldn't be allowed according to the test. I just understood the test cases as 'must start with letter'. Also, fixed the end.

Comment: Ooops, sorry missed that while trying to work out the edge cases from such a limited definition not covering edge cases. Noted the correction.

Answer (score 0):

The first peice of this:

> `^[\p{L}\d._]*\p{L}+[\p{L}\d._]*$`

has `*` which allows *zero* or more, first to fix issue #2 change that to a `+`: *one* or more:

```
^[\p{L}\d._]+\p{L}+[\p{L}\d._]*$.
```

To prevent underscores at the end need another clause which doesn't include `_`:

```
^[\p{L}\d._]+\p{L}+[\p{L}\d._]*[\p{L}\d.]?$.
```

But this would still allow a `_` alone (from the first part matching alone). If you don't want a sole underscore just remove from that first clause:

```
^[\p{L}\d.]+\p{L}+[\p{L}\d._]*[\p{L}\d.]?$.
```

If the ability to start with an underscore is needed I think we need more information about allowable cases for single and double character strings.

Comment: Starting with a numeric is disallowed according to test case 2.

Comment: @Keppil Correct. However when I realised the allow-ability of "`_.`" (for example) wasn't covered I just went with the final sentence. Underlying root cause of OP's issues is lack of a clear definition that encompasses full what is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your steps Richard, sorry that Im not clear in my question